# Fix Responsive mobile menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I have a menu from Hongkiat. I want to add to my site for having a mobile menu, because the actual one displays a basic dropdown that i don't like.

But this throws me error, something with `height`:

[image]

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub8Az/

Comment: Seems library error to me........http://jsfiddle.net/Ub8Az/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery missing, updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ub8Az/4/)

```
 $(function() {
      ----
      menu = $('ul.clearfix2');
      ----

});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when i resize the window for mobile phones the menu doesn't slide...

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga fixed check again

Comment: In the fiddle is correct but when i implement the same in my site it's throws the same error... :( Check http://www.healthot.com/

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga put your entire js code in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga sorry you dont need to put your code inside $(document).ready as it already inside ready function. just remove that it should work